Linux ls shows some abnormal files with “?” No message of desired type
Help me understand the following problem - there is software that interacts with files in XML format.
The software is wrapped in a docker container. When the software works with the file, the error "No message of desired type" occurs after a random time. When trying to see what is with the file in the container, by the path of its location, Linux responds that the file is there, but nothing can be done with it. For example, ls returns the following:`
# # ls -lah
ls: cannot access 'file.xml': No message of desired type
total 16K
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4.0K Nov 5 11:12 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4.0K Dec 4 12:42 ..
-????????? ? ? ? ? ? file.xml

No problems with the file system were found. When the container is restarted, the file is correct, but after some time the file breaks.
Made a copy of the files in the top level of the directory (while continuing to work with the internal files) - the external files remained intact, but the internal ones broke.
From the point of view of the code - the code is in C#, working with the file - opened for reading in FileStream, after work the stream was closed and disposed.
As far as we could understand, no one interacts with the file except the utility.

The access rights for the folder/file or the access rights when mounting are set incorrectly, or when creating or editing the file

@Z0OM This folder and files are not mounted in the docker-compose file.
The application is built in the Release configuration and the result is copied to the Dockerfile directly without mounting

This could mean the following "-?????????": The file is corrupted, the file type is unknown, or access is not possible for other reasons (missing permissions or a defective file system). In your case, it looks like the file is setting incorrect permissions when being created or the file is generated incorrectly.

Are multiple processes or threads access the file simultaneosly?

Did you take a look at similar questions on this site, such as this one?

if the problem was with access rights to the directory (the usual thing about the x permission missing), that should lead to errors like "permission denied" and then you also should not see . and .. either
